# How to get generators call other generators in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, generator

I am experimenting with gem development, right now specifically generators. So far I have successfully created two generators that do their job just perfectly. These two generators are in the same directory.

However, right now I have to call each of them separately.

What I'd like to do is just call one generator and have that generator call all the other ones. Just would type

```
rails g generator_name
```

and this would call x other generators.

Does anyone know how would I got about doing this?

Help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your generator, you can just call

```
generate "some:generator" # can be anything listed by 'rails g'
```

for example:

```
module MyGem
  class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base

    def run_other_generators
      generate "jquery:install" # or whatever you want here
    end

  end
end
```

By the way, if you are working on Rails 3 gems, this question can also help out:

[Rails 3 generators in gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577713/rails-3-generators-in-gem)

Comment: What about passing params into the invoked generator?

Comment: @ziggy generate 'generator', 'arguments'

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility is to use something like

```
invoke 'active_record:model', 'foo bar:string baz:float'
```

which is not as clean as `generate`, but has one advantage: When your generator gets called via `rails destroy`, this call -- like may other of Thors actions -- will try to revoke the action of the generator you `invoke`.

There's a catch however: Probably due to Thors dependency management, this only works once per generator you want to call, meaning that a second `invoke` of the same generator will do nothing. This can be circumvented by using a statement like

```
Rails::Generators.invoke 'active_record:model', '...', behavior: behavior
```

instead. In this case you have to explicitly pass through the `behavior` of your generator (which is a method returning values like `:invoke`, `:revoke` and possibly others, depending on which command -- `rails generate`, `rails destroy`, `rails update`, etc. -- called your generator) to achieve the same result as above. If you don't do this, the generator you call with `Rails::Generators.invoke` will also be executed when running your generator with `rails destroy`.

Alternatively you could stick to `invoke` and try to tamper with Thors invocation system. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5098855/1610268) for example.

Comment: you can also call invoke with a generator too e.g.  invoke 'cucumber:install'   ... the advantage of this is that it will correctly *undo* the command when you're trying to rollback the generator (with rails d mygenerator:mytask) .. hope that makes sense!

Comment: `Rails::Generators.invoke 'active_record:model', ["bar"], :migration => false` ignores the migration false flag or any options. Digging deeper it looks like the invoke method that is called when you just do "invoke ..." is not the same as Rails::Generators.invoke. So if you need to pass in generator options: `Rails::Generators.invoke 'active_record:model', ["bar", "--no-migration" ])`

Answer (score 1):

Generators are based off of Thor, so you can use the [apply method](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/thor/Thor/Actions#apply-instance_method).

This is what the [Rails Templater gem](https://github.com/kfaustino/rails-templater) does. ([Here's](http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/49) a walk through the Rails Templater gem.)

Comment: You might want to check your walkthrough link again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the scaffold generator that comes with rails.

> /Users/XYZ/sources/rails/railties/lib/rails_generator/generators/components/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb

```
def manifest
    record do |m|
      #....rest of the source is removed for brevity....
      m.dependency 'model', [name] + @args, :collision => :skip
    end
  end
```

Here the scaffold generator is using the model generator. So take a look at the dependency method. You can find the API docs for it over [here](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generator/Commands/Base.html#M001957).