# Unit testing a Rails generator that invokes another generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails generator I want to make that, amongst other things, will run some scaffolds based off of a yaml file:

```
class MyGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
    ...
    def run_scaffolds
        ...
        invoke 'scaffold', fields
        ...
    end
end
```

I'm invoking the scaffold generator as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890650/how-to-get-generators-call-other-generators-in-rails-3).

The problem is if I try and run this in a unit test:

```
class ScaffoldTest < Rails::Generators::TestCase
    tests MyGenerator
    destination File.expand_path("../tmp", File.dirname(__FILE__))
    setup :prepare_destination

    test "run scaffolds" do
        run_generator ["example_file.yaml"]
        # doesn't get to here
    end
end
```

I end up with an error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - .../tmp/config/routes.rb
```

This is because there is no Rails app in the tmp directory. My question is how can I possibly test this generator if it can't be executed without a rails app? Surely I shouldn't I be creating a new rails app in the tmp folder everytime I run my tests?

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to stub out the call to the generator using mocha:

```
Rails::Generator.stubs(:invoke)
run_generator ["example_file.yaml"]
```

I chose this solution because it let's me verify that the code is calling the generator with the correct arguments and it doesn't require that I actually run the generator in a real rails app.